# how to play video from my youtube account in android

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I want want to play video from my personal account in you tube.

```
  Intent videoClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  videoClient.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com"));
  videoClient.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube","com.google.android.youtube.PlayerActivity");
   startActivity(videoClient);
```

this code use for only play video in youtube. I want to play video into MY personal account in youtube..
I'm also log in in youtube.I have created my account in youtube and add video in my youtube account... question is this "how to play video on my youtube account"

Comment: " i want to play video into MY personal account in youtube.." you mean add to your favorites ?

Comment: yes i want to play MY personal account in YouTube. This is mean my favorites add in my YouTube account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For playing video from your youtube channel(account) you want to get rtsp URL of your video. And for complete example [click here](http://blog.blundellapps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.