# How to Play RTSP Video in Android?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, rtsp, youtube-channels

I want to play Youtube Video on VideoView . 
I have searched very much & find that VideoView Support rtsp URL Video .
 But I am getting error: My android device is 2.3.5 & using Wifi. 
    My VideoView Code is:

```
  final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        Button youtube=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       final  MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setScrollBarStyle(DEFAULT_KEYS_DISABLE);
        mediaController.setPressed(true);
         mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("rtsp://v3.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlOCTh0GvUeYRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp");
       // Uri video = Uri.parse(getUrlVideoRTSP("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mashable/uploads?&v=2"));
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
```

My LogCat Error is:

```
10-12 11:56:50.369: D/WindowManagerImpl(6880): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4055c4e0

10-12 11:56:50.430: I/AudioSystem(6880): getting audio flinger

10-12 11:56:50.430: I/AudioSystem(6880): returning new audio session id

10-12 11:56:50.430: D/MediaPlayer(6880): setDataSource(Context context, rtsp://v3.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlOCTh0GvUeYRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp, Map<String, String> headers) in

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): skip setting (httpproxyip,null)

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): skip setting (httpproxyport,null)

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): skip setting (rtspproxyip,null) 

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): skip setting (rtspproxyport,null) 

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): add setting (minudpport,1024)

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): add setting (maxudpport,65535)

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): add setting (buffertime,7)

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): add setting (rtsptimeout,25000)

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): add setting (rtptimeout,25000)

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): add setting (rtcpreportinterval,3000)

10-12 11:56:50.460: I/MediaPlayer(6880): add setting (rtspkeepaliveinterval,35000)
10-12 11:56:50.460: D/MediaPlayer(6880): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

10-12 11:56:50.470: I/MediaPlayer(6880): disable CIQ

10-12 11:56:50.470: D/MediaPlayer(6880): setDataSource(Context context, rtsp://v3.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlOCTh0GvUeYRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp, Map<String, String> headers) out

10-12 11:57:20.589: W/MediaPlayer(6880): info/warning (34355, 3000)

10-12 11:57:20.589: I/MediaPlayer(6880): Info (34355,3000)

10-12 11:57:20.599: E/MediaPlayer(6880): error (1, -1003)

10-12 11:57:20.599: E/MediaPlayer(6880): Error (1,-1003)

10-12 11:57:20.599: D/VideoView(6880): Error: 1,-1003
```

Comment: You are sure your URL of video is correct?

Comment: i think your URL is not right..

Comment: Sir, I have use url from Json. I have checked  on different urls. But Problem as it is. URL Is:- http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mashable/uploads?&v=2&alt=jsonc

Comment: look at my answer and any help regarding this told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get videos from your YOutube Channel. For this following Example will help you.

[See My answer Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034874/how-to-play-video-from-my-youtube-account-in-android/11184741#11184741) it will give you perfect idea about this.

Also for playing video in videoview you need rtsp format of your video.

You can convert your url in rtsp format i create function for that which is [HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937615/how-to-play-youtube-video-on-videoview/11185129#11185129)

Comment: I have already use Your code & Its convert in rtsp from http still video is not playing. same errrors...

Comment: @DeepankerChaudhary you get solution or not?

Comment: Nope! I am able playing video on webview through Intent But requirement is that I will show two buttons previous & next So I want to play video on VideoView.Something went wrong May be Mobile support problem.

Answer (score 1):

By using this way i play rtsp video in android.

```
    videourl="rtsp://..........";
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_View);
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Video.this, "",
            "Buffering video...", true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // progressDialog.dismiss();
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(Video.this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri video = Uri.parse(videourl);// insert video url 
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    sync = new myAsync();
    sync.execute();
    // PlayVideo();
}


private class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    int duration = 0;
    //int current = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                videoView.seekTo(check);
                videoView.start();
                duration = videoView.getDuration();
            }
        });

        do {


            current = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- "
                    + current);
            /*if(current/600==0)
            {
                //sync.cancel(true);

                videoView.pause();
                try {
                    wait(300000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();q
                }

                videoView.resume();

                videoView.seekTo(current);
            }*/


        }

            if (sync.isCancelled())
                break;

        } while (current != duration || current == 0);

        return null;
    }

}
```