# How to Fetch Playlists Videos fromYouTube

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I am writing an app in which i want to *Fetch List of YouTube Videos*, and i am able to do that by using a particular user's account like the below link:

```
 HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");
```

but if i want to fetch list of YouTube videos **using playlist**, so what are the changes i need to do in my code, like here i no need username to fetch videos.

```
  http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL1D5B07DD840FB46D?v=2&alt=json
```

*original link:*   http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1D5B07DD840FB46D

**My Code:**

```
  public class GetYouTubeUserVideosTask implements Runnable {

public static final String LIBRARY = "Library";
private final Handler replyTo;
private final String username;

public GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(Handler replyTo, String username) {
    this.replyTo = replyTo;
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL1D5B07DD840FB46D?v=2&alt=json");   
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");
        List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
            String url;
            try {
                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
            } catch (JSONException ignore) {
                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
            }

            String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault"); 
            videos.add(new Video(title, url, thumbUrl));
        }       
        Library lib = new Library(username, videos);

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putSerializable(LIBRARY, lib);

        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.setData(data);
        replyTo.sendMessage(msg);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("Feck", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Feck", e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Feck", e);
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: I'm not going to comment on your code, except to suggest you look at [Dave Chandlers blog](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/a-basic-http-client-for-android-and-more/) for how to do async HTTP requests. I like to use the [jsonc format](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc) and the [interactive demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/view_youtube_jsonc_responses) and using your example it suggests the URL: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL1D5B07DD840FB46D?v=2&alt=jsonc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new YouTube Data API v3 to get playlists:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists

In this tutorial that I wrote (in Spanish .. but you can see the code changes..):

http://fuse21.blogspot.com.ar/2013/01/utilizando-youtube-data-api-v3-desde.html

I show how to change the official sample "tasks-android-sample":

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/?repo=samples

to use the YouTube Data API instead of the Tasks API.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on it in my one project in which I display all videos from my youtube account and display it in video view.

For playing video from your youtube channel(account) you want to get rtsp URL of your video.

Follow [this example](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/) it will give you perfect idea.

Also refer [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854159/1405983).